# how do I initialize a const int member in class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, constants

I would to initialize a const int member (numGrids) of my class TestCase when I construct a TestCase.  It needs to be const (I think) because it defines the elements of another array member of the classwhich I would also like to initialize when I create a TestCase.  The code is shown below:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//TestCase.h

class TestCase

{

protected:

    const int numGrids;

    Grid meshes[numGrids];

public:

    TestCase(const int);

};


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//TestCases.cpp

TestCase::TestCase(const int numGridsSpec)

{
    numGrids = numGridsSpec;

    Grid grids[numGrids];

}
```

I cannot seem to initialize the const member of my class.  I need that member to be constant because it defines the array size of meshes.  I get the following errors:

```
[ 12%] Building CXX object sources/CMakeFiles/GridRefinementStudy.dir/TestCase.cpp.o
In file included from /home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/TestCase.cpp:16:0:

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/TestCase.h:5:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘TestCase::numGrids’

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/TestCase.h:6:14: error: from this location

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/TestCase.h:6:22: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/TestCase.cpp: In constructor ‘TestCase::TestCase(int)’:

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/TestCase.cpp:25:1: error: uninitialized member ‘TestCase::numGrids’ with ‘const’ type ‘const int’ [-fpermissive]

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/TestCase.cpp:28:13: error: assignment of read-only member ‘TestCase::numGrids’

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/TestCase.cpp:29:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘Grid::Grid()’

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/TestCase.cpp:29:21: note: candidates are:

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/Grid.h:13:2: note: Grid::Grid(int, int, double, double)

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/Grid.h:13:2: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/Grid.h:1:7: note: Grid::Grid(const Grid&)

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources/Grid.h:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

make[2]: *** [sources/CMakeFiles/GridRefinementStudy.dir/TestCase.cpp.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [sources/CMakeFiles/GridRefinementStudy.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Array sizes have to be compile-time constant expressions. You either want `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: You need initializer list to initialize constant. And I would suggest to change the array to std::vector.

Comment: Edit your code properly please! I started, leaving the rest for you ...

Comment: @KerrekSB He'll need a compile time constant for `std::array` too.

Comment: One (possibly ugly) solution would be to pass `size_t numGrids` as template argument as OP believes size of array is known at compile time.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, but that would be a lot more obvious than in the current approach.

Answer (score 1):

You may not do such a way. The size of the array shall be known at compile time. In fact you are trying to get a variable length array. C++ does not have such a feature.
Take into account that if the sizes of the array are different for two objects then the classes that define them are different types. They have different data members that is arrays with different sizes. The size of a class shall be the same for each object of that class.
I would suggest to use standard container `std::dynarray` if the compiler supports it or 
`std::vector`

On the other hand you could define your class as a template class. For example

```
template <size_t numGrids>
class TestCase {

protected:


Grid meshes[numGrids];

//...
```

or even as

```
template <size_t numGrids>
class TestCase {

protected:


std::array<Grid, numGrids> meshes;

//...
```

I think that using a template class is the best approach in your case.

Comment: OK, but would the array size not be known at compile time when I create a TestCase in main and specify a const value for it.  The class would have a variable size depending on how I initialize.  I should mention that I'm an amateur programmer.

Comment: @user3592458 I do not see sense in this approach because as I understood you want to define objects of the class with different array sizes.

Comment: @user3592458 If the size of the array is different for various objects then the classes that define them are also different types. So I advice to use a template class.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in your code. The array size is dynamic (a variable). You can't use a variable to declare an array size at compile time. Use some constants with real value.

To Answer your question

Initializer list is used to init the data for a const. Something as follows.

```
class TestCase {

    protected:
        const int numGrids;    

    public:

        TestCase(const int x) : numGrids(x)
        {
        }
};
```

Solution for your problem

```
class TestCase {

    protected:

        const int numGrids;
        Grid* pMeshes;

    public:

        TestCase(const int x) : numGrids(x)
        {
            pMeshes = new Grid[x];
        }

        ~TestCase() : numGrids(x)
        {
            delete []pMeshes; // release allocated memory in destructor
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TestCase t(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, I tried to edit my .cpp file as follows:

// Constructor for steady TestCase
TestCase::TestCase(const int numGridsSpec) :numGrids(numGridsSpec)

{

cout << "Hurray!" << endl;

}

I left the .h the same.

errors now:

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources

/TestCase.h:5:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 
‘TestCase::numGrids’

/home/omar/Documents/Programming/C++/FCFD/Current/sources

/TestCase.h:6:14: error: from this location

../TestCase.h:6:22: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token

Answer (score 0):

In pre-C++11, there are four ways of initializing a member:

- If the member is `static`, `const` and has an integral type,
  it can be initialized directly in the class definition.  In this
  case, the member is a "integral constant expression", and can be
  used anywhere the compiler requires such (e.g. array dimensions,
  template argument, etc.).
- If the member is `static`, it must be initialized in its
  definition.  If the member is also `const`, it is a constant
  expression in the translation unit which contains the
  definition, after the definition.
- Any member can be initialized in the initializer list, and
  typically, all should be (but there are exceptions).  Non-static
  const members *must* be initialized here (but non-static const
  members are *not* constant expressions, and cannot be used as
  such).
- Finally, non-const members can be "initialized" in the
  constructor body.  Formally, this is assignment, not initialization, and if
  the member type has a user defined constructor, it will still be
  initialized (using the default constructor) in the
  initialization list.  For primitive types, the member remains
  uninitialized if it isn't mentionned in the initializer list,
  until it is first assigned.

In your case, it would appear that you want an array whose size
is defined by a parameter to the constructor.  This is not
possible; the size of an array must be an integral constant
expression.  If the size should always be the same, then you can
use a static const int to define it:

```
class TestClass
{
    static int const numGrids = 25;
    Grid meshes[numGrids];
    //  ...
};
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use:

```
class TestClass
{
    std::vector<Grid> meshes;
public:
    TestClass( int size ) : meshes( size ) {}
};
```

This might be the better solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all since numGrids is const in the class declaration, you can only initialize it through initialization list.

```
TestCase::TestCase(const int numGridsSpec)
  :numGrids(numGridsSpec)   // this is the initialization list
{
... 
}
```

This is simply because a constant variable can only be set to a value once and can not be modified 'legally' thereafter, compilers normally would not allow you to proceed avoiding unexpected consequences in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports c++11, you could simply do:

```
class TestCase

{

protected:

    const int numGrids = 25;

    Grid meshes[numGrids];

public:

    TestCase(const int);

};
```